# implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime' error

Tags: c#

```
private DateTime? pApproveDate=null;
pApproveDate =(Reader["ApproveDate"]==DBNull.Value)?null: Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["ApproveDate"]);
```

Above code is generating the following error during compile time- 
**Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'System.DateTime'**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cast it to DateTime?:

```
private DateTime? 
pApproveDate=null;
pApproveDate =(Reader["ApproveDate"]==DBNull.Value)?(DateTime?)null:       
    Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["ApproveDate"]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
pApproveDate = (Reader["ApproveDate"]==DBNull.Value)
  ? (DateTime?)null 
  : Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["ApproveDate"]);
```

Since `ConvertToDateTime` returns a `DateTime` the conditional operator thinks you are returning mismatching types.

Comment: And you need to. This has been discussed in other questions already.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more simpler if you use normal if statement instead of conditional statement, you will **not be required to explicitly cast and it would be more readable** IMO

```
DateTime? pApproveDate = null;

if (Reader["ApproveDate"] == DBNull.Value)
    pApproveDate = null;
else
    pApproveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["ApproveDate"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The type that is returned from the lamda expression must be the same as the variable type you are assigning the value to. If it is not the same type, then you will get a compliation error because the compiler will try to put an implicit conversion in place.

DateTime is not a nullable type, so you either need to make it nullable type, or use a different conversion for the DBNull value.

Comment: Where do you see lambda expression ?